# Comparison of Int64 elements from two arrays in Metal

Tags: swift, macos, metal, int64

I would like to compare Int64 from two arrays using Metal. The Swift code for this comparison is the following:

```
    for each in arrayOfInt
    {
        for j in 0..<arrayOfArrayOfInt.endIndex
        {
            if arrayOfArrayOfInt[j].contains(each)
            {
                arrayOfIndeces.append(j)
            }
        }

        arrayOfarrayOfIndeces.append(arrayOfIndeces)
        arrayOfIndeces = [Int]()
    }
```

I have to write this in Metal. But first, I am not sure if I can do this at all since in documentation ([Metal-Shading-Language-Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)) I see that on one hand:

Metal supports the scalar - "An unsigned 64-bit integer" (ulong)

but from the other for buffer it can not be used.

"Note: Metal does not support buffers that contain long or ulong data types."

Do I understand something wrong from reading the documentation? Can somebody explain?

Comment: I don't think you actually want to do this in metal.  the algorithm is n^3; memoize the indicies in a single set and the whole thing is only O(n) and it will be dramatically faster.

Comment: @Josh Homann I need (for further analysis) to memorise the found indices for each array of Int64 from the array separately, in separate sets, not all indices in one set. But, question is remaining, can I use two dimensional array of Int64 for metal or I cannot compare Int64 in metal ?

Comment: You could probably declare the buffer elements as `uint`, take two adjacent elements, and reconstruct a `ulong`. `ulong val = ((ulong)b[i+1] << 32) | b[i];`